# Programmable USB RF transceiver

Tags: usb, wireless, rf

I've been trying, and failing, to find a USB RF tranceiver that I can program or that has an API I can use. Does anyone know if such a thing exists, or suggest how I could about creating one?

Comment: What is "an API I can use"?

Comment: @stevenvh: An Application Programming Interface. It's usually more relevant to software than hardware, but GFX cards have been implementing them over the last couple of years.

Comment: Yes I know what an API is, but it's a term so wide that it doesn't mean anything without specifying: what's the target development environment?

Comment: @stevenvh: Preferably Python (if that's what you mean). I'm looking to be able to write software to send instructions via RF to a device which will convert those instructions to physical movement. And sorry if I came across as trying to teach my granny to suck eggs :)

Comment: Does Python imply that the API is hardware and OS independent? I guess the API will be a shell on top of a driver, and these are platform specific. Please add anything that could be relevant for us to the question.

Comment: www.phidget.com have devices (but no RF ones that I can see) which have a standard C library converted to many different languages. So I suppose my question can be boiled down to 'is there an RF tranceiver which has a python (or even js) API?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect a suitable RF transceiver (I'm using the cheap nRF24L01+ modules that are available on Ebay) to a USB MCU, such as a PIC18F14K50.

Comment: Thanks. Having had a search for nRF24L01+, I've now found some devices that show potential.

Comment: @hellsgate would you mind providing links to whatever solution you ended up with?

Answer (score 0):

Theres are many rf modules available with RS232 interface  .You can buy these and connect them through a usb to RS232 converter.